# Wait Until Fetch Promise data is available and pass to react native component using Typescript TSX

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, tsx

I am very new to this style of coding. I am trying to not use express and doing some fetching in the front end.  If things should never be done this way then let me know.

I know my endpoint is working but fetch seems to give me a strange internal server error now.

Before I was getting data. I'm basically lost on grabbing data in typescript and using the data in typescript.  Let me know if anyone has suggestions on other ways to do this.

```js
const wait = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));


// TODO: figure out how get vars in here
async function getWorkerProfileData(searchQuery) {
    let graphQuery = `
        example
    `

    fetch("https://www.XXXX.com/graphql?query=" + graphQuery).then(function(response) {
        console.log("ONE")
        let myData = response.json();

        /*
        RETURNS THIS
        Object {
        "errors": Array [
            Object {
            "category": "internal",
            "locations": Array [
                Object {
                "column": 20,
                "line": 3,
                },
            ],
            "message": "Internal server error",
            },
        ],
        }
        */
        console.log(response.json())
        return myData;
    }).then(function(json) {
        console.log("tasdfasdfasdfasdf")
        console.log(json);
        return json;
    });
}

const worker = getWorkerProfileData( "d29ya2VyOjI0ODE")

const GetWorkerProfile = <Props, State, worker > ({searchQuery}) => (
    <Container>
        { console.log("DATA COMES BACK LIKE THIS: ", worker) }
        /*
        worker:  Promise {
            "_40": 0,
            "_55": null,
            "_65": 0,
            "_72": null,
        }
        */

        <Content>
            <List>
                <View>
                    <Content>
                        <Header
                            subheader={ "test"  }
                            content={ "test"  }
                        />
                    </Content>
                </View>
            </List>
        </Content>
    </Container>
);

export default GetWorkerProfile;
```

Comment: You should look into using apollo to query a GraphQL server from a React app. Also if you are getting an Internal Server Error (500) this means something is broken server side, not on the frontend. Debug your GraphQL server to see what is breaking.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried using Apollo with different results. I need to take a step back and figure it out.

The graphql server is working and at one time was logging data to console.

When I use postman,  it works as well. But something in the promise is messing it up

I will take your advice and try to use apollo again and directlly link to graphql without rest